# Endianness Of OpenCL devices

Tags: buffer, opencl, device, host, endianness

Apart from precision / accuracy / alignment inconsistencies between a gpu, a cpu and a customized opencl chip,  why all opencl examples over internet directly accept host-side buffers?

```
clEnqueueWriteBuffer (  cl_command_queue command, ...)

__kernel void vecAdd(__global float * c, ..)
{
   int id=get_global_id(0);
   c[id]=b[id]+a[id]
}
```

lets assume host is little endian but device is big endian and a,b,c, are floats:

- Would b and a be loaded as non-normalized garbage?

  - if yes, do I have to send a single byte telling kernel about buffer endianness?
  - if no, are they converted(using 4 byte SIMD shuffling of CPU? Or at GPU?) during buffer read-write operations  automatically? Even for USE_HOST_PTR(RAM) type buffers and CL_MEM_READ_WRITE(GDDR)?
  - If unknown, would below example functions work always?

    ```
        int endianness_of_device()
        {
                unsigned int x = 1;
                return ((  (  (char *)&x) [0])==0?0:1) ;
        }

        int reverseBytesInt(int bytes)
        {
            void * p = &bytes;
            uchar4 bytesr = ((uchar4 *)p)[0].wzyx;
            int * p2=(int *)&bytesr;
            return *p2;
        }

        float reverseBytesFloat(float bytes)
        {
            void * p = &bytes;
            uchar4 bytesr = ((uchar4 *)p)[0].wzyx;
            float * p2=(float *)&bytesr;
            return *p2;
        }

        uint sizeOf2(uint structSize)
        {
            uit mult0=structSize/256;mult0++;
            return mult0*256;
        }

        typedef struct
        {
            uchar end;
            uchar sizeRelByteAdr;
            uchar adrRelByteAdr;
            uchar idRelByteAdr;
            uchar valRelByteAdr;
            uchar woRelByteAdr;
            int size;
            uint adr; 
            int id;
            float val;
            float wo;
        }nn_p_n;




        uint malloc(__global uchar * heap, __global uint * mallocCtr, int size)
        {
            return (atomic_add(mallocCtr,(uint)size)+(uint)heap);
        }
    ```

to help kernels like:

```
           __kernel void nn( __global uchar *heap,__global uint * mallocCtr)
                        {
                            int id=get_global_id(0);
                            if(id==0)
                            {

                                nn_p_n * np=(nn_p_n *)malloc(heap,mallocCtr,sizeOf2(sizeof(nn_p_n)));
                                np->end=endianness_of_device();
                                np->size=sizeOf2(sizeof(nn_p_n));
                                np->id=9;
                                np->val=99.9f;

                                // lets simulate different endianness
                                np->end=1-endianness_of_device();


                                np->adr=(uint)np-(uint)heap;

                                mem_fence(CLK_GLOBAL_MEM_FENCE);
                            }

                            if(id==900)
                            {
                                // simulating another device reads buffer
                                for(int i=0;i<1000000;i++){int dummy=0; dummy++; if(dummy>id) dummy++;}

                                nn_p_n n=*((nn_p_n *)&heap[0]);
                                if(n.end!=endianness_of_device())
                                {
                                    n.size=reverseBytesInt(n.size);
                                    //if(n.size!=sizeof2(sizeof(nn_p_n)))
                                    //{  return; }
                                    n.adr=reverseBytesInt(n.adr);
                                    n.val=reverseBytesFloat(n.val);
                                }
                                nn_p_n * np=(nn_p_n *)malloc(heap,mallocCtr,sizeOf2(sizeof(nn_p_n)));
                                *np = n;
                            }

                        }
```

because it is working for my Intel igpu with an Intel CPU at the moment and other machine with Amd CPU and Amd GPU without any endianness problems. What if I get Nvidia gpu and Amd gpu on top of Intel CPU in future?

Ofcourse in cluster computing, one needs to cover endianness cases between computers but what about a virtual os running in another os and using same device? What about that device is an fpga having multiple endianness cores(possible?)?

Last question: can an OS force all devices, even the CPU, to become same endianness?(I don't think so but could be emulated by OS at a cost of performance?)

Edit:  It's impossible to preprocess a read-only data on device-side. It is overkill to postprocess on host side those elements which are marked as "written" because only 1-2 elements could have been written while whole data could be gigabytes to download to host.

Comment: According to @Gundolf Gundelfinger, there is no perfect code, there is perfect hardware setup.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Arguments passed to kernels are guaranteed to have the correct endianness (hence all the typedefs `cl_int`, etc), but this is not the case for buffers. This makes sense, because the contents of buffers are completely opaque for OpenCL: only the user knows how to make sense of what's inside. Hence, it's the user's responsibility to perform potential endianness conversion before doing computations (possibly by launching a dedicated kernel).

In other words:

```
__kernel void vecAdd(__global float * c, ..)
```

Here, the *value* of `c` is guaranteed to be of the correct endianness (the pointer's bytes themselves are in the correct device order), but the bytes *pointed to* by `c` are in whatever order the user set them on the host.

> why all opencl examples over internet directly accept host-side buffers?

Most programs are developed with a fairly narrow set of target platforms, where characteristics are known in advance: if they're all little-endian, why bother supporting big-endian?  Portability is already a difficult problem, and I suspect that caring about endianness is, in the general case, a significant additional complexity for little added value. It simply isn't worth it for the vast majority of programs.

If you consider such a level of portability valuable, then it's your choice to implement it.

Comment: I agree. Is there even a real-world example of an OpenCL device that doesn't match the endianness of the host?

Comment: Uncommon these days, but NVIDIA GPU on a PowerPC host.

Comment: Ooh, actually you'd have to use AMD, due to driver issues, and probably a Linux OS.